# Nuxt SSR setting causes Tailwind media query to crash

Tags: nuxt.js, server-side-rendering, tailwind-css

I am having an issue with CSS purging with Tailwind and Nuxt. I am able to isolate the issue to between `ssr: false` and `ssr: true` setting in nuxt config.

**Issue**

When I use `ssr: true` with a `target: static` (full-static). The media query would disappear.

**Expected Behaviour**

CSS purging should be identical whether SSR is true or false.

**Viewing the Problem**

- A working site with SSR - false (SPA mode): [Link](https://beyond-web.netlify.app/en/)
- A non-functional site with SSR - true (Full-static): [Link](https://5fd79820b7f37e11a04ec6db--beyond-web.netlify.app/en/)

Under a working site, if you view the CSS of a responsive element you would see the media query, like so:

```html
<div class="hidden lg:block"> ... </div>
```

```
@media (min-width: 1024px)
.lg\:block {
    display: block;
}
```

In the non-functional site, the `lg:block` class would be missing, and `lg:hidden` would loses its media query and became just

```
.lg\:hidden { display: hidden; }
```

You can check the Hamburger menu will be hidden whatever screen size you have.

Does anyone have any clue on what I may have done wrong?

I have also attached my `tailwind.config.js` here for reference

```js
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    darkSelector: '.dark-mode',
    inset: {
      0: 0,
      auto: 'auto',
      '1/2': '50%',
      '-16': '-4rem',
    },
    flexGrow: {
      0: 0,
      1: 1,
      2: 2,
      3: 3,
      default: 1,
    },
    extend: {
      colors: {
        primary: 'var(--color-primary)',
        secondary: 'var(--color-secondary)',
        ld_gray: {
          100: 'var(--color-body-100)',
          200: 'var(--color-body-200)',
          300: 'var(--color-body-300)',
          400: 'var(--color-body-400)',
          500: 'var(--color-body-500)',
          600: 'var(--color-body-600)',
          700: 'var(--color-body-700)',
          800: 'var(--color-body-800)',
          900: 'var(--color-body-900)',
        },
        background: {
          primary: 'var(--color-background-primary)',
        },
        border: {
          primary: 'var(--color-border-primary)',
        },
      },
      spacing: {
        '1/3': '33.3333333%',
        '2/3': '66.6666667%',
        '1/5': '20%',
        '2/5': '40%',
        '3/5': '60%',
      },
      fontSize: {
        xxs: '.625rem',
      },
      fontFamily: {
        display: ['Oswald', 'Noto Sans TC'],
        body: ['Raleway', 'Noto Sans TC'],
        headline: ['Playfair Display', 'Noto Sans TC'],
      },
      transitionDelay: {
        0: '0ms',
      },
      screens: {
        'xs-only': { max: '639px' },
        'sm-only': { min: '640px', max: '767px' },
        'md-only': { min: '768px', max: '1023px' },
        'lg-only': { min: '1024px', max: '1279px' },
      },
    },
  },
  variants: {
    display: [
      'responsive',
      'hover',
      'focus',
      'active',
      'group-hover',
      'dark',
      'dark-hover',
    ],
    backgroundColor: [
      'responsive',
      'hover',
      'focus',
      'active',
      'group-hover',
      'dark',
      'dark-hover',
      'dark-group-hover',
      'dark-even',
      'dark-odd',
    ],
    backgroundOpacity: [
      'responsive',
      'hover',
      'focus',
      'active',
      'group-hover',
      'dark',
      'dark-hover',
      'dark-group-hover',
      'dark-even',
      'dark-odd',
    ],
    textColor: [
      'responsive',
      'hover',
      'focus',
      'active',
      'group-hover',
      'dark',
      'dark-hover',
      'dark-group-hover',
      'dark-active',
    ],
    borderColor: [
      'responsive',
      'focus',
      'hover',
      'dark',
      'dark-focus',
      'dark-hover',
      'dark-focus-within',
    ],
    rotate: ['responsive', 'hover', 'group-hover', 'active', 'dark'],
  },
  plugins: [
    require('tailwindcss-dark-mode')(), // https://github.com/ChanceArthur/tailwindcss-dark-mode
    require('@tailwindcss/custom-forms'),
  ],
  purge: {
    // Learn more on https://tailwindcss.com/docs/controlling-file-size/#removing-unused-css
    enabled: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
    content: [
      'components/**/*.vue',
      'layouts/**/*.vue',
      'pages/**/*.vue',
      'plugins/**/*.js',
      'nuxt.config.js',
    ],
    options: {
      whitelist: ['dark-mode'],
      variables: false,
    },
  },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just had a very similar issue to yours, but only when using `ssr: false` and `target: static` for full-static build.
Turns out that TailwindCSS is using PurgeCSS to remove unused styles at build time.
For reasons unknown, PurgeCSS removes all media query styles in production build.
I looked everywhere and you're the only person who had a similar issue, I wonder if you solved that yet?
For me, I had to use a custom options for PurgeCSS at `tailwind.config.js`, which instructs PurgeCSS to keep a list of regex rules matching the responsive styles I need in my app.

```js
module.exports = {
  purge: {
    options: {
      safelist: [
        'md:grid-cols-12',
        /^md:col-start-/,
        /^md:col-span-/,
        /^md:row-start-/,
        /^md:row-span-/,
      ]
    }
  },
```

Only then I was able to build an optimized static export in production mode.